# JavaFx add child to custom node

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, nodes, borderpane

I have a custom node that extends BorderPane:

```
package main.resources.nodes;

import ...

public class DragNode extends BorderPane {

    public DragNode () {

        setNodes();

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/main/resources/fxml/DragNode.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setNodes() {

        Circle inpNode = new Circle();
        this.getChildren().add(inpNode);

        inpNode.setRadius(10.0);
        inpNode.setCenterX(this.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX());
        inpNode.setCenterY(this.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY() / 2.0);

        System.out.println(this.getBoundsInParent());   // Prints 'BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:-5.0, ... ]'
        System.out.println(this.getParent());           // Prints null
        System.out.println(this.getChildren());         // Prints 1
    }
}
```

I would like to create a circle that is on the *right middle edge* of the DragNode -- so the right middle edge of the BorderPane.

When I set the circle's position to be this.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxX or inpNode.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX it never seems to return the right value.

How do I get the width of the BorderPane that the class is extending?

Thanks in advance. I hope the question makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomended way is to add the all the `Nodes` using `SceneBuilder` or directly with `fxml` and not in the code.

> Althought here you have to wait `FXMLLoader` to initialize the fxml
>   layout or otherwise you may have problems:

```
public class DragNode extends BorderPane implements Initializable{

    public DragNode () {


        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/main/resources/fxml/DragNode.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

      //call it here so you are sure fxml layout has been initialized
      setNodes();

    }

    private void setNodes() {

        Circle inpNode = new Circle();
        this.getChildren().add(inpNode);

        inpNode.setRadius(10.0);
        inpNode.setCenterX(this.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX());
        inpNode.setCenterY(this.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY() / 2.0);

        System.out.println(this.getBoundsInParent());   // Prints 'BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:-5.0, ... ]'
        System.out.println(this.getParent());           // Prints null
        System.out.println(this.getChildren());         // Prints 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for that! Also, do you know how to access the width of the BorderPane? I tried inpNode.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() but the value doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: @user3668541 Try to do this after the `setNodes();`  has been called `borderPane.getWidth();`.Mention that JavaFX will just return zero for the height and width of the BorderPane until it has executed a layout pass on it.Also if you want to be informed about the width and height better you have to use listeners along with `widthProperty()` and `heightProperty()`

Comment: Fixed! Needed inpNode.getParent.getPrefWidth(-1). Thankyou!

Comment: @user36668541 `inpNode.getParent.getPrefWidth(-1)` that doesn't exist...

Comment: Woops, typed it in from memory and typed it wrong. I'd edit my comment but I'm not sure how to do that. I ended up using this.getPrefWidth(-1), which *does* work :)

Comment: @user3668541 You mean `this.getPrefWidth()` :) ... To edit a comment must not have been past 5 minutes,or else you can not edit it again.Also if you want to add some code in comments for example `code` (you have to use ` and after that one more `)